# Add date on Presentations (Open XML SDK) on C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

My reference is [Presentations (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/presentations)

With the code-behind below I add the date on existing PowerPoint.

This code working and in the first slide the date is added, but it's possible customize the point on the page where to insert this date? The font and size ?

This is current output:

[image]

Thank you in advance for help.

```
string fileName = @"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\aspnet\\Template\\01_FOCUS.pptx";

using (PresentationDocument oPDoc = PresentationDocument.Open(fileName, true))
{
            PresentationPart oPPart = oPDoc.PresentationPart;
            SlideIdList slideIdList = oPPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;
            SlidePart sp = slideIdList.ChildElements
           .Cast<SlideId>()
           .Select(x => oPPart.GetPartById(x.RelationshipId))
           .Cast<SlidePart>().First();
            AddDateToSlidePart(sp);
}

public static void AddDateToSlidePart(SlidePart slidePart1)
{
    Slide slide1 = slidePart1.Slide;
    CommonSlideData commonSlideData1 = slide1.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();
    ShapeTree shapeTree1 = commonSlideData1.GetFirstChild<ShapeTree>();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape shape1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeProperties nonVisualShapeProperties1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeProperties();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualDrawingProperties nonVisualDrawingProperties1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)4U, Name = "Date Placeholder 3" };

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeLocks shapeLocks1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true };

    nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties1.Append(shapeLocks1);

    ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties1 =
        new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties();

    PlaceholderShape placeholderShape1 =
        new PlaceholderShape() { Type = PlaceholderValues.DateAndTime, Size = PlaceholderSizeValues.Half, Index = (UInt32Value)10U };

    applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties1.Append(placeholderShape1);
    nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(nonVisualDrawingProperties1);
    nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties1);
    nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties1);

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ShapeProperties shapeProperties1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ShapeProperties();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.TextBody textBody1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.TextBody();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BodyProperties bodyProperties1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BodyProperties();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ListStyle listStyle1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ListStyle();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph paragraph1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Field field1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Field() { Id = "{528B97E8-8E4B-4D32-BA17-4F287283DFD6}", Type = "datetime1" };

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.RunProperties runProperties1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.RunProperties() { Language = "it-IT" };

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text text1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text();

    text1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");

    field1.Append(runProperties1);
    field1.Append(text1);

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties1 =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "it-IT" };

    paragraph1.Append(field1);
    paragraph1.Append(endParagraphRunProperties1);
    textBody1.Append(bodyProperties1);
    textBody1.Append(listStyle1);
    textBody1.Append(paragraph1);
    shape1.Append(nonVisualShapeProperties1);
    shape1.Append(shapeProperties1);
    shape1.Append(textBody1);
    shapeTree1.Append(shape1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenXML SDK Productivity tool (downloadable from the Microsoft site) is your friend here.  When I need to do something like this, I:

1. Create the document I want
2. Open it in the appropriate tool (PowerPoint in this case).
3. Make a tiny change (to "dirty" the document and make PowerPoint believe it needs to be changed).
4. Save the result
5. Make the changes to the document that I want to see, and save the result with a new name
6. Open the OpenXML Productivity Tool and click the "Compare Files" tool.

The reason I force a save (in steps 3/4) is so that PowerPoint can add all of it's PowerPoint-ness to the document I created.  The second save (step 5) will necessarily have all of that, so I want the two documents as close as possible - with only the "changes to the document that I want to see" being the difference between the two documents.

At this point, you should see a path to a solution to your problem.  That tool is indispensable when working with OOXML.